# App crashing when starts an activity with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

The app crashes in Android Studio when a button is clicked to reach the another activity through intent

```
public void next(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Next called " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class));     
}
```

The error I am getting from logcat is

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:  Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {com.example.utkarsh.internalstorage/com.example.utkarsh.internalstorage.SecondActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Have you checked your manifest? Post your manifest please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, the **SecondActivity** `Activity` wasn't added to the [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).  Once you add that as an application node, it will work properly.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.utkarsh.internalstorage.SecondActivity" />
```

Comment: Happy to hear that. You can always accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark if it helps. ty

Answer (score 1):

specify activity in your android manifest file 
`<activity android:name="SecondActivity"> </activity>`

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clear, define your activity in your manifest